# How many if conditions should I use in Razor View Engine MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, if-statement

I used too many IF conditions in my MVC3 Razor view - almost 230 if conditions on the to compare two or more values. The problem is that it's using too much memory and processor on the server. That's why server response time is very slow over 6 sec average.

What should I do? Should I reduce using If conditions or is there any alternative?

(I can post my code here too)

Update with Code:

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string query)
           {
            name1 = query.Substring(0, query.IndexOf("-vs-"));
            name2 = query.Substring(query.IndexOf("-vs-") + 1, query.Length - query.IndexOf("-vs-") - 1);
            name2 = name2.Replace("vs-", "");
var model = _comp.GetViewModel(name1 , name2 );
```

}

Mode:

```
 public CpusViewModel GetViewModel(int? id1, int? id2)
    {
        if (id1 == null) return null;
        if (id2 == null) return null;

        var cpu1 = _comp.Get(p => p.cpuId == id1);
        if (cpu1 == null) return null;

        var cpu2 = _comp.Get(p => p.cpuId == id2);
        if (cpu2 == null) return null;

        return new CpusViewModel
        {
            CPUId1 = cpu1.cpuId,
            CPUImage1 = cpu1.cpuImageName,
            CPUImageFolder1 = cpu1.cpuImageName.Substring(0,1),
            CpuMunafacturer1 = cpu1.cpuMunafacturer,
            CpuFamily1 = cpu1.cpuFamily,
            CpuModel1 = cpu1.cpuModel,
            CpuQuery1 = cpu1.cpuQuery,
            CpuTitle1 = cpu1.cpuQuery.Replace("-"," "),
            CpuSummaryClockSpeedNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuSummaryClockSpeedNodeText,
            CpuSummaryCoredNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuSummaryCoredNodeText,
            CpuSummaryIsUnlockedNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuSummaryIsUnlockedNodeText,
            CpuFeaturedReview1 = cpu1.cpuFeaturedReview,
            CpuFeaturedReviewLinkAndDate1 = cpu1.cpuFeaturedReviewLinkAndDate,
            CpusortMainBassScore1 = cpu1.cpuBossValueScoreNew,
            CpuOverclockingScoreNew1 = cpu1.cpuOverclockingScoreNew,
            CpuSingleCorePerformanceScoreNew1 = cpu1.cpuSingleCorePerformanceScoreNew,
            CpusortBenchmarkPerformanceScoreNew1 = cpu1.cpusortBenchmarkPerformanceScoreNew,
            CpuValueScoreNew1 = cpu1.cpuValueScoreNew,
            CpuBenchmaKX264HD4PASS1NodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmaKX264HD4PASS1NodeText,
            CpuBenchmaKX264HD4PASS2NodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmaKX264HD4PASS2NodeText,
            CpuBenchmaCinebenchR1032BitNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmaCinebenchR1032BitNodeText,
            CpuBenchmaCinebenchR1032Bit1CoreNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmaCinebenchR1032Bit1CoreNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkPerformancePerDollarNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmarkPerformancePerDollarNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkSysMark20073DNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmarkSysMark20073DNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkSysMark2007ProductivityNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmarkSysMark2007ProductivityNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkSysMark2007VideoCreationNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmarkSysMark2007VideoCreationNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkCinebenchR11_5NodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmarkCinebenchR11_5NodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkCinebenchR11_5_SingleNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmarkCinebenchR11_5_SingleNodeText,
            CpuBenchmark3DMark06CPUNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmark3DMark06CPUNodeText,
            CpuBenchmark3DMark11PhysicsNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmark3DMark11PhysicsNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkPassMarkNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmarkPassMarkNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkPassMarkSingleCoreNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmarkPassMarkSingleCoreNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkGeekBenchNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmarkGeekBenchNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkX264HD4NodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmarkX264HD4NodeText,
            CpuBenchmarSysMark2007OverallNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBenchmarSysMark2007OverallNodeText,
            CpuGeneralCodeNameNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuGeneralCodeNameNodeText,
            CpuGeneralMarketNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuGeneralMarketNodeText,
            CpuGeneralManuProductPageNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuGeneralManuProductPageNodeText,
            CpuSummaryTurboClockSpeedNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuSummaryTurboClockSpeedNodeText,
            CpuSummarySocketTypeNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuSummarySocketTypeNodeText,
            CpuSummaryIsHyperthreadedNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuSummaryIsHyperthreadedNodeText,
            CpuDetailsArchitectureNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuDetailsArchitectureNodeText,
            CpuDetailsThreadsNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuDetailsThreadsNodeText,
            CpuDetailsL2CacheNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuDetailsL2CacheNodeText,
            CpuDetailsL2CachePerCoreNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuDetailsL2CachePerCoreNodeText,
            CpuDetailsL3CacheNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuDetailsL3CacheNodeText,
            CpuDetailsL3CachePerCoreNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuDetailsL3CachePerCoreNodeText,
            CpuDetailsManufactureProcessNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuDetailsManufactureProcessNodeText,
            CpuDetailsTransistorCountNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuDetailsTransistorCountNodeText,
            CpuDetailsMaxCPUsNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuDetailsMaxCPUsNodeText,
            CpuDetailsClockMultiplierNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuDetailsClockMultiplierNodeText,
            CpuDetailsVoltageRangeNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuDetailsVoltageRangeNodeText,
            CpuDetailsOperatingTempNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuDetailsOperatingTempNodeText,
            CpuFeaturesNXBitNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuFeaturesNXBitNodeText,
            CpuFeaturesTrustedComputingNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuFeaturesTrustedComputingNodeText,
            CpuFeaturesVirtualizationSupportNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuFeaturesVirtualizationSupportNodeText,
            CpuFeaturesInstructionSetExtensionsNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuFeaturesInstructionSetExtensionsNodeText,
            CpuFeaturesDynamicFrequencyScalingNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuFeaturesDynamicFrequencyScalingNodeText,
            CpuOverclockingOverclockPopulartyNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuOverclockingOverclockPopulartyNodeText,
            CpuOverclockingOverclockReviewScoreNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuOverclockingOverclockReviewScoreNodeText,
            CpuOverclockingOverclockedClockSpeedNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuOverclockingOverclockedClockSpeedNodeText,
            CpuOverclockingOverclockedClockSpeedWaterNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuOverclockingOverclockedClockSpeedWaterNodeText,
            CpuOverclockingPassmarkOverclockedNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuOverclockingPassmarkOverclockedNodeText,
            CpuOverclockingOverclockedClockSpeedAirNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuOverclockingOverclockedClockSpeedAirNodeText,
            CpuGPUGpuNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuGPUGpuNodeText,
            CpuGPULabelNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuGPULabelNodeText,
            CpuGPULatestDirectXNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuGPULatestDirectXNodeText,
            CpuGPUNumberDisplaysSupportedNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuGPUNumberDisplaysSupportedNodeText,
            CpuGPUClockSpeedNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuGPUClockSpeedNodeText,
            CpuGPUTurboClockSpeedNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuGPUTurboClockSpeedNodeText,
            CpuGPU3DMark06NodeText1 = cpu1.cpuGPU3DMark06NodeText,
            CpuPowerTDPNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuPowerTDPNodeText,
            CpuPowerAnnualHomeEnergyCostNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuPowerAnnualHomeEnergyCostNodeText,
            CpuPowerAnnualCommercialEnergyCostNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuPowerAnnualCommercialEnergyCostNodeText,
            CpuPowerPerformancePerWattNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuPowerPerformancePerWattNodeText,
            CpuPowerIdlePowerConsumptionNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuPowerIdlePowerConsumptionNodeText,
            CpuPowerPeakPowerConsumptionNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuPowerPeakPowerConsumptionNodeText,
            CpuPowerTypicalPowerConsumptionNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuPowerTypicalPowerConsumptionNodeText,
            CpuMemoryControllerNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuMemoryControllerNodeText,
            CpuMemoryTypeNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuMemoryTypeNodeText,
            CpuMemoryContollerChannelsNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuMemoryContollerChannelsNodeText,
            CpuMemorySupportsECCNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuMemorySupportsECCNodeText,
            CpuMemoryMaximumBandwidthNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuMemoryMaximumBandwidthNodeText,
            CpuMemoryMaximumMemorySizeNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuMemoryMaximumMemorySizeNodeText,
            CpuBusArchitectureNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBusArchitectureNodeText,
            CpuBusNumberOfLinksNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBusNumberOfLinksNodeText,
            CpuBusTransferRateNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBusTransferRateNodeText,
            CpuBusDataRateNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBusDataRateNodeText,
            CpuBusClockSpeedNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuBusClockSpeedNodeText,
            CpuMobileBenchmarkglbenchmark_2_1_egypt_offscreenNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuMobileBenchmarkglbenchmark_2_1_egypt_offscreenNodeText,
            CpuMobileBenchmarkprop_glbenchmark_2_5_egypt_classic_offscreenNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuMobileBenchmarkprop_glbenchmark_2_5_egypt_classic_offscreenNodeText,
            CpuMobileBenchmarkprop_sunspider_0_9_1NodeText1 = cpu1.cpuMobileBenchmarkprop_sunspider_0_9_1NodeText,
            CpuMobileBenchmarkprop_browsermarkNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuMobileBenchmarkprop_browsermarkNodeText,
            CpuMobileBenchmarkprop_browsermark_2NodeText1 = cpu1.cpuMobileBenchmarkprop_browsermark_2NodeText,
            CpuGeneralAnnoucedDateNodeTextSmall1 = cpu1.cpuGeneralAnnoucedDateNodeTextSmall,
            CpuGeneralExpectedDateNodeTextSmall1 = cpu1.cpuGeneralExpectedDateNodeTextSmall,
            CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall1 = cpu1.cpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall,
            CpuGeneralAnnoucedDateNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuGeneralAnnoucedDateNodeText,
            CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeText,
            CpuGeneralExpectedDateNodeText1 = cpu1.cpuGeneralExpectedDateNodeText,

            CPUId2 = cpu2.cpuId,
            CPUImage2 = cpu2.cpuImageName,
            CPUImageFolder2 = cpu2.cpuImageName.Substring(0, 1),
            CpuMunafacturer2 = cpu2.cpuMunafacturer,
            CpuFamily2 = cpu2.cpuFamily,
            CpuModel2 = cpu2.cpuModel,
            CpuQuery2 = cpu2.cpuQuery,
            CpuTitle2 = cpu2.cpuQuery.Replace("-", " "),
            CpuSummaryClockSpeedNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuSummaryClockSpeedNodeText,
            CpuSummaryCoredNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuSummaryCoredNodeText,
            CpuSummaryIsUnlockedNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuSummaryIsUnlockedNodeText,
            CpuFeaturedReview2 = cpu2.cpuFeaturedReview,
            CpuFeaturedReviewLinkAndDate2 = cpu2.cpuFeaturedReviewLinkAndDate,
            CpusortMainBassScore2 = cpu2.cpuBossValueScoreNew,
            CpuOverclockingScoreNew2 = cpu2.cpuOverclockingScoreNew,
            CpuSingleCorePerformanceScoreNew2 = cpu2.cpuSingleCorePerformanceScoreNew,
            CpusortBenchmarkPerformanceScoreNew2 = cpu2.cpusortBenchmarkPerformanceScoreNew,
            CpuValueScoreNew2 = cpu2.cpuValueScoreNew,
            CpuBenchmaKX264HD4PASS1NodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmaKX264HD4PASS1NodeText,
            CpuBenchmaKX264HD4PASS2NodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmaKX264HD4PASS2NodeText,
            CpuBenchmaCinebenchR1032BitNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmaCinebenchR1032BitNodeText,
            CpuBenchmaCinebenchR1032Bit1CoreNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmaCinebenchR1032Bit1CoreNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkPerformancePerDollarNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmarkPerformancePerDollarNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkSysMark20073DNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmarkSysMark20073DNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkSysMark2007ProductivityNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmarkSysMark2007ProductivityNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkSysMark2007VideoCreationNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmarkSysMark2007VideoCreationNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkCinebenchR11_5NodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmarkCinebenchR11_5NodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkCinebenchR11_5_SingleNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmarkCinebenchR11_5_SingleNodeText,
            CpuBenchmark3DMark06CPUNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmark3DMark06CPUNodeText,
            CpuBenchmark3DMark11PhysicsNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmark3DMark11PhysicsNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkPassMarkNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmarkPassMarkNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkPassMarkSingleCoreNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmarkPassMarkSingleCoreNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkGeekBenchNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmarkGeekBenchNodeText,
            CpuBenchmarkX264HD4NodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmarkX264HD4NodeText,
            CpuBenchmarSysMark2007OverallNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBenchmarSysMark2007OverallNodeText,
            CpuGeneralCodeNameNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuGeneralCodeNameNodeText,
            CpuGeneralMarketNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuGeneralMarketNodeText,
            CpuGeneralManuProductPageNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuGeneralManuProductPageNodeText,
            CpuSummaryTurboClockSpeedNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuSummaryTurboClockSpeedNodeText,
            CpuSummarySocketTypeNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuSummarySocketTypeNodeText,
            CpuSummaryIsHyperthreadedNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuSummaryIsHyperthreadedNodeText,
            CpuDetailsArchitectureNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuDetailsArchitectureNodeText,
            CpuDetailsThreadsNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuDetailsThreadsNodeText,
            CpuDetailsL2CacheNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuDetailsL2CacheNodeText,
            CpuDetailsL2CachePerCoreNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuDetailsL2CachePerCoreNodeText,
            CpuDetailsL3CacheNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuDetailsL3CacheNodeText,
            CpuDetailsL3CachePerCoreNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuDetailsL3CachePerCoreNodeText,
            CpuDetailsManufactureProcessNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuDetailsManufactureProcessNodeText,
            CpuDetailsTransistorCountNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuDetailsTransistorCountNodeText,
            CpuDetailsMaxCPUsNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuDetailsMaxCPUsNodeText,
            CpuDetailsClockMultiplierNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuDetailsClockMultiplierNodeText,
            CpuDetailsVoltageRangeNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuDetailsVoltageRangeNodeText,
            CpuDetailsOperatingTempNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuDetailsOperatingTempNodeText,
            CpuFeaturesNXBitNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuFeaturesNXBitNodeText,
            CpuFeaturesTrustedComputingNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuFeaturesTrustedComputingNodeText,
            CpuFeaturesVirtualizationSupportNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuFeaturesVirtualizationSupportNodeText,
            CpuFeaturesInstructionSetExtensionsNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuFeaturesInstructionSetExtensionsNodeText,
            CpuFeaturesDynamicFrequencyScalingNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuFeaturesDynamicFrequencyScalingNodeText,
            CpuOverclockingOverclockPopulartyNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuOverclockingOverclockPopulartyNodeText,
            CpuOverclockingOverclockReviewScoreNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuOverclockingOverclockReviewScoreNodeText,
            CpuOverclockingOverclockedClockSpeedNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuOverclockingOverclockedClockSpeedNodeText,
            CpuOverclockingOverclockedClockSpeedWaterNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuOverclockingOverclockedClockSpeedWaterNodeText,
            CpuOverclockingPassmarkOverclockedNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuOverclockingPassmarkOverclockedNodeText,
            CpuOverclockingOverclockedClockSpeedAirNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuOverclockingOverclockedClockSpeedAirNodeText,
            CpuGPUGpuNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuGPUGpuNodeText,
            CpuGPULabelNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuGPULabelNodeText,
            CpuGPULatestDirectXNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuGPULatestDirectXNodeText,
            CpuGPUNumberDisplaysSupportedNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuGPUNumberDisplaysSupportedNodeText,
            CpuGPUClockSpeedNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuGPUClockSpeedNodeText,
            CpuGPUTurboClockSpeedNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuGPUTurboClockSpeedNodeText,
            CpuGPU3DMark06NodeText2 = cpu2.cpuGPU3DMark06NodeText,
            CpuPowerTDPNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuPowerTDPNodeText,
            CpuPowerAnnualHomeEnergyCostNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuPowerAnnualHomeEnergyCostNodeText,
            CpuPowerAnnualCommercialEnergyCostNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuPowerAnnualCommercialEnergyCostNodeText,
            CpuPowerPerformancePerWattNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuPowerPerformancePerWattNodeText,
            CpuPowerIdlePowerConsumptionNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuPowerIdlePowerConsumptionNodeText,
            CpuPowerPeakPowerConsumptionNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuPowerPeakPowerConsumptionNodeText,
            CpuPowerTypicalPowerConsumptionNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuPowerTypicalPowerConsumptionNodeText,
            CpuMemoryControllerNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuMemoryControllerNodeText,
            CpuMemoryTypeNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuMemoryTypeNodeText,
            CpuMemoryContollerChannelsNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuMemoryContollerChannelsNodeText,
            CpuMemorySupportsECCNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuMemorySupportsECCNodeText,
            CpuMemoryMaximumBandwidthNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuMemoryMaximumBandwidthNodeText,
            CpuMemoryMaximumMemorySizeNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuMemoryMaximumMemorySizeNodeText,
            CpuBusArchitectureNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBusArchitectureNodeText,
            CpuBusNumberOfLinksNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBusNumberOfLinksNodeText,
            CpuBusTransferRateNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBusTransferRateNodeText,
            CpuBusDataRateNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBusDataRateNodeText,
            CpuBusClockSpeedNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuBusClockSpeedNodeText,
            CpuMobileBenchmarkglbenchmark_2_1_egypt_offscreenNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuMobileBenchmarkglbenchmark_2_1_egypt_offscreenNodeText,
            CpuMobileBenchmarkprop_glbenchmark_2_5_egypt_classic_offscreenNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuMobileBenchmarkprop_glbenchmark_2_5_egypt_classic_offscreenNodeText,
            CpuMobileBenchmarkprop_sunspider_0_9_1NodeText2 = cpu2.cpuMobileBenchmarkprop_sunspider_0_9_1NodeText,
            CpuMobileBenchmarkprop_browsermarkNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuMobileBenchmarkprop_browsermarkNodeText,
            CpuMobileBenchmarkprop_browsermark_2NodeText2 = cpu2.cpuMobileBenchmarkprop_browsermark_2NodeText,
            CpuGeneralAnnoucedDateNodeTextSmall2 = cpu2.cpuGeneralAnnoucedDateNodeTextSmall,
            CpuGeneralExpectedDateNodeTextSmall2 = cpu2.cpuGeneralExpectedDateNodeTextSmall,
            CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall2 = cpu2.cpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall,
            CpuGeneralAnnoucedDateNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuGeneralAnnoucedDateNodeText,
            CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeText,
            CpuGeneralExpectedDateNodeText2 = cpu2.cpuGeneralExpectedDateNodeText
        };
    }
```

View (Used the values like this):

```
    @{
if (Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall1 != null)
{
    if ((DateTime.UtcNow - Convert.ToDateTime(Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall1)).TotalDays < 31.0)
    {       
         @("Released ") @Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeText1; <span class="justreleasedbadge">@("Just Released")</span>
    }
    else if ((DateTime.UtcNow - Convert.ToDateTime(Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall1)).TotalDays > 31.0 && (DateTime.UtcNow - Convert.ToDateTime(Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall1)).TotalDays < 120.0)
    { 
         @("Released ") @Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeText1; <span class="newbadge">@("New")</span>
    }
    else if ((DateTime.UtcNow - Convert.ToDateTime(Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall1)).TotalDays > 120.0 && (DateTime.UtcNow - Convert.ToDateTime(Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall1)).TotalDays < 365.0)
    { 
        @("Released ") @Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeText1;
    }
    else if ((DateTime.UtcNow - Convert.ToDateTime(Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall1)).TotalDays > 365.0)
    { 
        @("Released ") @Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeText1; <span class="olderbadge">@("Older")</span>
    }

}
else if (Model.CpuGeneralAnnoucedDateNodeTextSmall1 != null && Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall1 == null)
{ 
          @Model.CpuGeneralAnnoucedDateNodeText1; <span class="comingsoonbadge">@("Coming Soon")</span> @("Annouced ")
}
else if (Model.CpuGeneralExpectedDateNodeTextSmall1 != null && Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall1 == null && Model.CpuGeneralAnnoucedDateNodeTextSmall1 == null)
{ 
          @("First seen on ") @Model.CpuGeneralExpectedDateNodeText1; <span class="rumoredbadge">@("Rumored")</span>
}
}
</span>
</div>
<div class="comparelinkTitle"><a href="@Url.Content("~/Cpu/" + @Model.CpuQuery1)"><span style="font-size:20px;">@Model.CpuMunafacturer1 @Model.CpuFamily1 @Model.CpuModel1</span></a></div>
<div class="h1small2">
@Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Model.CpuSummaryClockSpeedNodeText1), 1) GHz
@{
if (Model.CpuSummaryCoredNodeText1 != "Unknown")
{
        @("| "); @Model.CpuSummaryCoredNodeText1;
}
}
@{
if (Model.CpuSummaryIsUnlockedNodeText1 != "Unknown")
{
    if (Model.CpuSummaryIsUnlockedNodeText1 == "Yes")
    {
            @(" | Unlocked");
    }
    else
    {
            @("");
    }
}
}
</div>
<div id="pnlContainer" style="text-align:right">
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Cpu/" + @Model.CpuQuery1)"><img alt="@Model.CpuMunafacturer1 @Model.CpuFamily1 @Model.CpuModel1" class="imgclass3" style="max-width:370px" src="http://img.cpusort.com/@Model.CPUImageFolder1/@Model.CPUImage1" /></a>
@if (Model.CpusortMainBassScore1 != 0 && Model.CpusortMainBassScore2 != 0 && Model.CpuGeneralMarketNodeText1 != "Mobile" && Model.CpuGeneralMarketNodeText2 != "Mobile")
{
<div class="dragDiv" style="right:0px" id="dragDiv">
<span class="scoretextsmall">@Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Model.CpusortMainBassScore1), 1)</span>
<span class="scoreunits" style="color:#fff">Out of 10</span>
</div>
}
else if (Model.CpusortMainBassScore1 != 0 && Model.CpusortMainBassScore2 != 0 && Model.CpuGeneralMarketNodeText1 == "Mobile" && Model.CpuGeneralMarketNodeText2 == "Mobile")
{
<div class="dragDiv" style="right:0px" id="dragDiv">
<span class="scoretextsmall">@Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Model.CpusortMainBassScore1), 1)</span>
<span class="scoreunits" style="color:#fff">Out of 10</span>
</div>
}
</div>
@if (Model.CpuFeaturedReview1 != null)
{
<blockquote>@Model.CpuFeaturedReview1</blockquote>
<span style="padding-left:18px;">@Html.Raw(Model.CpuFeaturedReviewLinkAndDate1)</span>
}
</td>
<td style="width:50%; padding:0px 0px 10px 20px; text-align:left;">
<div style="float:right">
<span class="comparesmall" style="vertical-align:middle" >
@{
if (Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall2 != null)
{
    if ((DateTime.UtcNow - Convert.ToDateTime(Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall2)).TotalDays < 31.0)
    {       
         <span class="justreleasedbadge">@("Just Released")</span> @("Released") @Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeText2;
    }
    else if ((DateTime.UtcNow - Convert.ToDateTime(Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall2)).TotalDays > 31.0 && (DateTime.UtcNow - Convert.ToDateTime(Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall2)).TotalDays < 120.0)
    { 
         <span class="newbadge">@("New")</span> @("Released ") @Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeText2;
    }
    else if ((DateTime.UtcNow - Convert.ToDateTime(Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall2)).TotalDays > 120.0 && (DateTime.UtcNow - Convert.ToDateTime(Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall2)).TotalDays < 365.0)
    { 
        @("Released ") @Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeText2;
    }
    else if ((DateTime.UtcNow - Convert.ToDateTime(Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall2)).TotalDays > 365.0)
    { 
        <span class="olderbadge">@("Older")</span> @("Released ") @Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeText2;
    }

}
else if (Model.CpuGeneralAnnoucedDateNodeTextSmall2 != null && Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall2 == null)
{ 
         <span class="comingsoonbadge">@("Coming Soon")</span> @("Annouced ") @Model.CpuGeneralAnnoucedDateNodeText2;
}
else if (Model.CpuGeneralExpectedDateNodeTextSmall2 != null && Model.CpuGeneralRleasedDateNodeTextSmall2 == null && Model.CpuGeneralAnnoucedDateNodeTextSmall2 == null)
{ 
         <span class="rumoredbadge">@("Rumored")</span> @("First seen on ") @Model.CpuGeneralExpectedDateNodeText2;
}
}
</span>
</div>
<div class="comparelinkTitle"><a href="@Url.Content("~/Cpu/" + @Model.CpuQuery2)"><span style="font-size:20px; line-height:22px">@Model.CpuMunafacturer2 @Model.CpuFamily2 @Model.CpuModel2</span></a></div> 
<div class="h1small2">
@Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Model.CpuSummaryClockSpeedNodeText2), 1) GHz
@{
if (Model.CpuSummaryCoredNodeText2 != "Unknown")
{
        @("| "); @Model.CpuSummaryCoredNodeText2;
}
}
@{
if (Model.CpuSummaryIsUnlockedNodeText2 != "Unknown")
{
    if (Model.CpuSummaryIsUnlockedNodeText2 == "Yes")
    {
            @(" | Unlocked");
    }
    else
    {
            @("");
    }
}
}
</div>
<div id="pnlContainer" style="text-align:left">
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Cpu/" + @Model.CpuQuery2)"><img alt="@Model.CpuMunafacturer2 @Model.CpuFamily2 @Model.CpuModel2" class="imgclass2" style="max-width:370px" src="http://img.cpusort.com/@Model.CPUImageFolder2/@Model.CPUImage2" /></a>
@if (Model.CpusortMainBassScore1 != 0 && Model.CpusortMainBassScore2 != 0 && Model.CpuGeneralMarketNodeText1 != "Mobile" && Model.CpuGeneralMarketNodeText2 != "Mobile")
{
<div class="dragDiv" style="left:0px" id="dragDiv">
<span class="scoretextsmall">@Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Model.CpusortMainBassScore2), 1)</span>
<span class="scoreunits" style="color:#fff">Out of 10</span>
</div>
}
else if (Model.CpusortMainBassScore1 != 0 && Model.CpusortMainBassScore2 != 0 && Model.CpuGeneralMarketNodeText1 == "Mobile" && Model.CpuGeneralMarketNodeText2 == "Mobile")
{
<div class="dragDiv" style="left:0px" id="dragDiv">
<span class="scoretextsmall">@Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Model.CpusortMainBassScore2), 1)</span>
<span class="scoreunits" style="color:#fff">Out of 10</span>
</div>
}
</div>
@if (Model.CpuFeaturedReview2 != null)
{
<blockquote>@Model.CpuFeaturedReview2</blockquote>
<span style="padding-left:18px;">@Html.Raw(Model.CpuFeaturedReviewLinkAndDate2)</span>
}
</td>
}
```

Comment: You meant *too many* IFs. This question is more about application logic and the best practices when programming on MVC. Is your Controller doing enough?

Comment: I'd be interested to see some code if only to find out how you can structure logic to have 230 `if` blocks for just printing two things side by side. Unfortunately, though, I suspect the answer to this question will boil down to "substantially rewrite your application logic to have some kind of sane structure", and that may be well beyond the scope of a single StackOverflow answer.

Comment: I can think of 230 reasons why you shouldn't have that amount of if statements in a razor file. :D

Comment: @MelanciaUK: Controller is just passing the query to Model to get the values from DB and then I pass it to ViewModel to use in my View.

Comment: The `View` shouldn't need to care about what's coming in to be displayed. That's the beauty about MVC. Total separation. Check the answer posted by @Abbas.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: I just updated my question with Code, Please check it

Comment: At a first glance, I may suggest that you compact your Model. You have all the properties duplicated just because you're working with 2 CPUs. What are you planning to do when you're working with more than this number?

Comment: @MelanciaUK: In two CPUs comparisons, I need to get two different values of each CPU. Because in specs one CPU have one advantage and other don't. But I compared both values on VIEW to show which CPU is better and why. Any suggestion?

Comment: You could have a single Model containing the common properties shared between any processor, and an extended one containing the particular properties for each one. In the end, every object instantiation (CPU) will be an instance of the same Model (class). Got it?

Comment: It's unlikely that all those if statements are causing your performance problems.  if statements do not cause much memory to be allocated, nor doe they take much time to execute.  It's still not good to have it be that large, but I don't think this is the cause of your problems.

Comment: @MystereMan: Yes you are right, It wasn't because of If statements, but there was a issue in the server after a specific update. However I have removed If from View, because its bad practice and wrote a custom HTMLHelper to manage the code. And now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why, oh why do you have such an amount of checks in your VIEW? MVC is all about the separation of the data, the logic and the things you show to the users. I'm pretty sure a lot of these if-statements can be avoided by letting the controller handle these. After the controller has handled these, a clean result of data should be passed to the view. This will increase performance a lot!

Comment: Well, I query to controller, then Model to get data from DB, then I pass it to ViewModel to use in the View. There I am using conditions. Should I use conditions is Model instead of View?

Comment: Conditions should be handled in your controller. The controller then fills the viewmodel, based on these conditions and then the viewmodel should be passed to the view.

Comment: I'm not so sure him moving 230 if conditions from a view to the controller is going to matter much. The view result is still getting executed on the server and sent to the client as html. I think his architecture is fundamentally flawed if he even needs so many if conditions to display a single view.

Comment: Well, I need to learn a lot, as it was my first MVC application. I thought View shouldn't bother what to compare or what to not, But as it also execute on server to generate HTML, so processor and RAM does bother.

Comment: @Abbas: Yes, Now I will transfer most of the conditions into controller.